# Uri for resourcedictionary from another assembly

Tags: wpf, uri, resourcedictionary

I have styles assemblies and i have to load on the fly.

When i refer the assembly from out side of "UserThemes" folder is working fine. As given below
"pack://application:,,,/Styles110;component/Themes/SIGreen.xaml"

Then I have moved styles110 assembly into UserThemes folder and tried, this way it is not working.
"pack://application:,,,/UserThemes/Styles110;component/Themes/SIGreen.xaml"
Please guide me this.

Regards,
Raman